# Make menu flags slide in a fixed menu while I scroll up & down a page

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

[my demo](http://www.aidahk.org/dev/testing/mission.html)

The above link is my responsive design layout with single page fixed menu.

I want to make the menu flags slide in a fixed menu. For example, at first I clicked section 2 menu button. The menu flags will highlight section 2. Secondly, the menu flags can move from section 2 to section 1 automatically while I use the mouse scrolling up to section 1. How can I do that?

js code

```
var menuContainer = $('header').height();

function scrollToAnchor(anchorName) {
  var aTag = $("div[name='" + anchorName + "']");
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: aTag.offset().top - menuContainer
  }, 'slow');
  console.log(anchorName);
}
$(window).on('resize', function(event) {
   menuContainer = $('header').height();
});
```

css code

```
/* header - navigation */
#subnav {
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 120%;

}
#submenu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 650px;
}
#submenu li {
    float: left;
}
#submenu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-right: 1px solid #294C52;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.submenu-active {
    background-color: #294C52;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
}
a {
  color: #294C52;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add handler for `scroll` event to check current scroll position and highlight appropriate menu section.

```
function menuHighlight() {
    /* compare your content offset top width $(document).scrollTop() 
       and highlight needed section of menu */
}
$(window).on('scroll', menuHighlight);
```

Also you need to add this check for resize event handler

```
$(window).on('resize', menuHighlight);
```

After that you can remove old method of menu highlighting, it will highlight automatically now.

I hope I understood your problem correctly and it can help you.